# Identify User with special NTFS access permission

Tags: powershell, acl

I am executing this command to get the users and their permissions:

```
Get-Acl $path | 
    select -ExpandProperty Access | 
    where { $_.IdentityReference -match "Users" } |
    select -Property * -ExcludeProperty IsInherited |
    Format-Table
```

```
           FileSystemRights AccessControlType IdentityReference                InheritanceFlags PropagationFlags
           ---------------- ----------------- -----------------                ---------------- ----------------
ReadAndExecute, Synchronize             Allow BUILTIN\Users     ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit             None
                 AppendData             Allow BUILTIN\Users                    ContainerInherit             None
                CreateFiles             Allow BUILTIN\Users                    ContainerInherit             None
```

In this one user has access as **Special**. I need to remove that user.

[image]

Please need your help to identify that user.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do. What exactly do you mean by _remove that user_?

Comment: I have added a picture. need to remove this user.

Comment: That's not a user, it's a builtin group, the same you're showing us with `Get-Acl` :)

Comment: I am not very much aware of this but it is showing 3 User right..?

Comment: No, it's showing the __same__ group with different Access Control Lists.

Comment: Then how to identify which principal is with access special. need to identify that and remove

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_descriptor this should help you understand what "Special" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Special` just refers to a list of filesystem access rights that don't match up with one of the named presets like `Read` or `Write`.

In your case, `BUILTIN\Users` has the `ReadAndExecute` preset in the first entry, but also has the `AppendData`, and `CreateFiles` rights. These two rights aren't the full `Write` permission, so they show up as `Special`.

If you want to remove those specific rights for your `BUILTIN\Users` group, you can use something like this:

```
$path = 'C:\temp\temp'
$acl = get-acl $path

# Check the existing rights
$acl.Access | where IdentityReference -Like 'BUILTIN\Users'

# Get a list of the rules to remove
$rules = $acl.access | Where-Object { 
    !$_.IsInherited -and 
    $_.IdentityReference -like 'BUILTIN\Users' -and
    $_.FileSystemRights -in 'AppendData','CreateFiles'
}

# Remove those rules from the ACL object 
ForEach($rule in $rules) {
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($rule)
}

# Check that the remaining rules look good:
$acl.Access

# Finally, set the ACL
# WARNING: setting file permissions can of course lock you out of files, so be careful!
Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
```

---

Please be aware that the example in your question shows those two permissions are already applying to subfolders as well, via `InheritanceFlags: ContainerInherit`. So when you update the ACL, it will try to apply changes to all subfolders.

If you're really trying to remove permission entries on the root of C:\ like your screenshot, you may run into issues on subfolders you don't have permission to.

Comment: I tried the code. It is executing without any error but the the access is not getting removed

Comment: @EmptyCoder What does `$acl.Access` show for your group after running the `.RemoveAccessRule()` method? There should only be `ReadAndExecute, Synchronize` remaining if the permissions were exactly like in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Cpt.Whale for your help

Below code solved my issue.

```
$path = 'C:\temp'
$acl = get-acl $path


##Remove Inheritance from Top Folders and Child Objects
Foreach($folder in $path) { 
 icacls $folder /inheritance:d
 Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Recurse | ?{$_.PSisContainer} | foreach {$subfolder = $_.FullName; icacls $subfolder /inheritance:d}
}


# Check the existing rights
$acl.Access | where IdentityReference -Like 'BUILTIN\Users'

# Get a list of the rules to remove
$rules = $acl.access | Where-Object { 
    !$_.IsInherited -and 
    $_.IdentityReference -like 'BUILTIN\Users' -and
    $_.FileSystemRights -in 'CreateFiles, AppendData'
}

# Remove those rules from the ACL object 
ForEach($rule in $rules) {
    $acl.RemoveAccessRule($rule)
}

# Check that the remaining rules look good:
$acl.Access

# Finally, set the ACL

Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $acl
```